# Getting in frame stop codons from fasta

Tags: python

I need to find a start codon and all in frame stop codons related to that primary start codon, i.e startCodon_AGGAAG_stopCodon(1)_GAAGGTAACAGCTCTG_stopCodon(2)_ATCAAGA. This is my code, which gives me the positions of all ORF. How can I modify it to achive positions of start codon and all in frame stop codons related to that primary start codon.

```
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio import SeqIO
def getORF(sequence, treshold, start_codons, stop_codons):
    orfs = []
    for j in range(0, 3):
        start_codon_index = 0
        end_codon_index = 0
        start_codon_found = False
        for indx in range(j, len(sequence), 3):
            current_codon = sequence[indx:indx+3]
            if current_codon in start_codons and not start_codon_found:
                start_codon_found = True
                start_codon_index = indx
                s=start_codon_index+1
            if current_codon in stop_codons and start_codon_found:
                end_codon_index = indx
                e=end_codon_index+3
                length = end_codon_index - start_codon_index + 3
                if length >= treshold * 3:
                    orfs.append(s)
                    orfs.append(e)
                start_codon_found = False
    return orfs
f = open("myfile.fa","r")
o = open("out.txt","w")
start = ["ATG"]
stop = ["TAA","TAG","TGA"]
for record in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'):
    seq=record.seq
    #compl_seq =record.seq.reverse_complement()
    name=record.id
    orfs = getORF(seq, 30, start, stop)
    #complement_orfs = getComplementORF(compl_seq, 30, start, stop)
    print >> o, name, '+', orfs, '-', complement_orfs
```